# Login with WebService running in background

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, asynchronous, authentication

I have a WebService that validates the user. But until you receive the validation Windows accuses the program not responding. I've tried with threads, async and have not had success. While he connects to the webservice a connecting message shows on the screen.

```
label1.Text = "Connecting";
Service.Service1 ws = new Service.Service1(); //start WebService
bool login = ws.login(username, password); //Validate login
if (login) {... //If login is true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried with threads,

You haven't really shown what you have tried, so it is hard to tell what might be wrong with your code. If this is a desktop application you might consider using a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

For example:

```
private void LoginButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Connecting";
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += Login;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += LoginCompleted;
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Login(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Service.Service1 ws = new Service.Service1();
    bool success = = ws.login(username, password);
    e.Result = success;
}

private LoginCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    bool success = (bool)e.Result;
    if (success)
    {
        label1.Text = "You have successfully logged in";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "Wrong username and password";
    }
}
```

Also be careful when using background threads in desktop applications. You should make sure that you never access your UI controls inside this background thread. This should always be done on the main UI thread.

Comment: I've tried this:
               `bool login = false;
            loginThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Service.Service1 ws = new Service.Service1(); //start WebService
      login = ws.login(username, password); //Validate login
                });
            loginThread.IsBackground = true;
            loginThread.Start();

            if(!loginThread.isAlive)
            {
                        Thread.Sleep(1);
            }`

Comment: Your code seems fine. You are performing the web service call inside a background thread which shouldn't freeze the main thread.

Comment: Thank you. Now working as I wanted. I do not know the BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Does Service1.Service have a "Beginlogin" / "Endlogin" method? Normally when you add a reference to a WSDL this async versions are auto-created for you as well....

If so, then use this method; it's much cleaner than spinning up a separate thread. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2476/Asynchronous-Communication-with-NET-WebServices for a good example of how to use them.